# wireshark: how to capture traffic between guest and host OS?

Tags: virtualbox, ipv6, wireshark

I'm trying to set up a lab to demonstrate ipv6 attack and detection mechanism on my Macbook. This is my set up with virtualbox:

- Host OS: OS X 10.8.2 IPv6 automatically, wireless connection Geust
- OS: Ubuntu 8.04 IPv6 enable, bridged network

Everything is working. I tested ping6 to see if both host and guest is reachable each other. So I turned on wireshark on host OS, and see if I can capture traffic when guest OS pings to it. Unfortunately, I didn't see any traffic coming from guest OS and not sure why. Since guest OS uses bridged network, it supposes to ask route to find who possess the ipv6 address, thus I believe the physical network card get involved in it. But I'm not sure why wireshark cannot capture any traffic

Answer (score 8):

Apparently, [VirtualBox itself can write all packets to or from a guest to a pcap file](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Network_tips), so that might be one way to do this.

In [Wes Morgan's answer to a similar VirtualBox question](http://ask.wireshark.org/questions/755/wireshark-with-virtual-box), he says that bridged mode is "bypassing the host OS network stack entirely", which may mean that packets between the host and guest aren't seen by BPF on OS X and thus aren't available to Wireshark (which uses libpcap, which uses BPF on OS X).